# Springframework tomcat error on the Intellij IDE

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea, h2

i didn't install tomcat because i'm taking course on udemy and the man who is publish this course
didn't mention this kind of problem and how can you configure tomcat into your intellij 
i tried couple stuff but i didn't get a success at all

1. BookController.java this is my Controller class

```
@Controller
public class BookController {

    private final BookRepository bookRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/books")
    public String getBooks(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("books",bookRepository.findAll());
        return "books";
    }

    public BookController(BookRepository bookRepository) {
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
    }
}
```

2.list.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Spring SARAÇ</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Book List</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Publisher</th>
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="book : ${books}">
        <td th:text="${book.id}">123</td>
        <td th:text="${book.title}"></td>
        <td th:text="${book.publisher.name}"></td>

    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

3. Console result

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.2.RELEASE)

2020-06-04 14:45:54.458  INFO 7768 --- [           main] a.s.s.Spring5webappApplication           : Starting Spring5webappApplication on DESKTOP-DA7D6TG with PID 7768 (C:\Users\SARAC\git\FirstSpringProject\spring5webapp\target\classes started by SARAC in C:\Users\SARAC\git\FirstSpringProject\spring5webapp)
2020-06-04 14:45:54.464  INFO 7768 --- [           main] a.s.s.Spring5webappApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-06-04 14:45:55.900  INFO 7768 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-06-04 14:45:55.971  INFO 7768 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 63ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-06-04 14:45:56.274  INFO 7768 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-06-04 14:45:56.557  INFO 7768 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-06-04 14:45:56.568  INFO 7768 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-06-04 14:45:56.569  INFO 7768 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.29]
2020-06-04 14:45:57.105  INFO 7768 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-06-04 14:45:57.105  INFO 7768 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2532 ms
2020-06-04 14:45:57.243  INFO 7768 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-06-04 14:45:57.388  INFO 7768 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-06-04 14:45:57.443  INFO 7768 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-06-04 14:45:57.538  INFO 7768 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.9.Final}
2020-06-04 14:45:57.784  INFO 7768 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-06-04 14:45:57.946  INFO 7768 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2020-06-04 14:45:58.840  INFO 7768 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-06-04 14:45:58.847  INFO 7768 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-06-04 14:45:59.188  WARN 7768 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-06-04 14:45:59.322  INFO 7768 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-06-04 14:45:59.480  WARN 7768 --- [           main] ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
2020-06-04 14:45:59.589  INFO 7768 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-06-04 14:45:59.591  INFO 7768 --- [           main] a.s.s.Spring5webappApplication           : Started Spring5webappApplication in 5.849 seconds (JVM running for 7.414)
Started in Bootstrap
Publisher Count: 1
Number of Books: 2
Publisher Number of Books: 2
2020-06-04 14:46:06.922  INFO 7768 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-06-04 14:46:06.922  INFO 7768 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-06-04 14:46:06.932  INFO 7768 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 10 ms
2020-06-04 14:46:07.134 ERROR 7768 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "error": Error resolving template [error], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [error], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:869) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) [thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) [thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:394) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:253) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:175) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]

2020-06-04 14:46:07.137 ERROR 7768 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [error], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:869) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:394) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:253) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:175) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]

2020-06-04 14:46:07.138 ERROR 7768 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [error], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:394) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:253) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:175) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [error], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:869) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

4. This is what I see in my browser

[image: This is what I see in my browser]

Comment: It looks like your RequestMapping is mapping the `/books` path but your browser has you browsing at the `/` path (root). Can you try `localhost:8080/books`?

Answer (score 2):

> `Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [error], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers`

You're using **Spring MVC**'s `@Controller`, which depends on the `View Resolver` when you don't return `@ResponseBody` from your method. `String`, which you return from method, is being looked up as a view name (in your case `.html` name).

Make sure you have `books.html` or return the name of your view file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `return "list"` instead of  `return "books"`

"list" is the name of your template.